# Algorithm that uses second powers of linear series

Tags: algorithm

I'm not quite sure if it should come here or on mathematics stack exchange, posting here to find more practical cases.

Is there any formula / algorithm that uses second powers of linear series?
Meaning: a(1)^2 + a(2)^2 + a(3)^2 + ... + a(n)^2

Where a(n) is linear series.

Answer (score 0):

Let a_k = a_0 + d°(k-1)

Then: (I use ° for multiplication)

sum(a_k^2) = sum( (a_0 + d°(k-1))^2) =sum( a_0^2 + d°d°(k-1)^2 + 2°d°(k-1)) = n°a_0°a_0 + d°d°sum((k-1)^2) + 2°d°sum(k-1)

(The sum goes from 1 to n)
We know that sum(k) = n°(n+1)/2, and sum(k^2)=n°(n+1)°(2n+1)/6

Therefore the above

sum(a_k^2) = n°a_0°a_0 + d°d°(n-1)°n°(2n-1)/6 + 2°(n-1)°n/2

Which can be simplified a little more, and be calculated in constant time.